# GWTP Code Splitting

Tags: gwt, gwt-gin, gwt-platform

I am using GWTP (MVP framework by Google) with GWT 2.3.
I want to use GWT code splitting with my presenters.

I know about `@ProxyCodeSplit` annotation in Presenters. Like below

```
@ProxyCodeSplit
@UseGatekeeper(LoggedInGatekeeper.class)
public interface MyProxy extends Proxy<MainPagePresenter> {
}
```

Is this sufficient ? Or Do I need to dig out GWT Code Splitting which provides `A call to GWT.runAsync` like [Here](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideCodeSplitting.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, GWTP will take care of calling `GWT.runAsync` for you, whenever the corresponding Presenter is shown.
However make sure that you use `AsyncProvider` in your `Ginjector`:

```
@GinModules({ MyModule.class })
public interface MyGinjector extends Ginjector {
  PlaceManager getPlaceManager();
  EventBus getEventBus();
  AsyncProvider<MainPagePresenter> getMainPagePresenter();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Umit. I just wanted to confirm. We have already "AsyncProvider" in "Ginjector" and Presenters marked as "@ProxyCodeSplit". It is working..So, I am accepting your answer.

Comment: For further confirmation you can also use **Firebug** or **Chrome Developer Tools** to check if a XHR request is created when you navigate to a Presenter which is marked with ``@ProxyCodeSplit``